# Focus through TextBoxes with arrows keys in C#

Tags: c#, forms, keyboard-shortcuts

I have many textboxes on this form; how can I use arrow keys to focusing one by one?

Or how can I make the code below more easy and readable?

This code is basic and use for limited textboxes I think but I can't rewrite the same lines into each textbox.

40 is for Down key, 38 is for up key

[my form picture, please see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLmZx.png)

```
private void t1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyValue == 40) { t1a.Focus(); }
    if (e.KeyValue == 38) { t1c.Focus(); }
}

private void t1a_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyValue == 40) { t1b.Focus(); }
    if (e.KeyValue == 38) { t1.Focus(); }
}

private void t1b_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyValue == 40) { t1c.Focus(); }
    if (e.KeyValue == 38) { t1a.Focus(); }
}

private void t1c_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyValue == 40) { t1.Focus(); }
    if (e.KeyValue == 38) { t1b.Focus(); }
}
```

Comment: The tab key and back-tab (shift tab) are the standard keys to use for navigating through fields in a form.  Don't use arrow keys to navigate--that is non-standard and will only confuse users used to the standard.

Comment: @Russ you right, but I like to use it like Excel cells do

Comment: Okay, but using Tab and back-tab means no C# code required.  Tab/Backtab functionality is built in.

Comment: If you use a TableLayoutPanel, then you could write completely generic code that finds the next control in the same row/column.  You wouldn't need to hard-code any associations between the different TextBoxes.

Answer (score 0):

An idea I have would be:

You have a variable (`int counter = 0;`) and a list of TextBoxes (`List<TextBox> textBoxes = new();`). In the list, there are all the TextBoxes you use, arranged in the order you want them to be clicked through.

For example:

```
private void PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyValue == 40) { counter--; }
    else if (e.KeyValue == 38) { counter++; }
    textBoxes[counter].Focus();
}
```

The idea is that the integer `counter` represents the index of the TextBox in the list `textBoxes` which currently has the focus. When clicking the buttons, it changes the focused TextBox through the variable `counter` and gets its focus.

Note that this event-method has to be assigned to all the TextBoxes!

Hope it's what you're looking for and it helps you!

Comment: thanks, this is perfect, but their is a little bit issue, when i press a down key i got this `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection` and works fine when i select the 3th textboxes and pressed down key i think i should put if condition

Comment: OK, nice I could help you. The error can, as you said, be handled by an if-statement (not decreasing ´counter´ if it is 0 and not increasing if it is already the last TextBox...

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to catch the pressed key directly from the FORM.
To do this you must enable the `KeyPreview` property. More info here [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview?view=net-5.0)

**You can use**:

```
    void MainFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e) 
      { 
       this.KeyPreview=true;        
      }
```

**Then**:

```
    void MainFormKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {   
        
        // Make a list of textBoxes
        List<string> mylist = new List<string>(new string[] { "t1", "t1a" , "t1b",  "t1c"});
        
        //Get the name of CurrentTextBox
        string CurrentTextBox=ActiveControl.Name;
        
        //Get the index of the CurrentTextBox in textBoxes list
        int index= mylist.IndexOf(CurrentTextBox);
        
        //Check the KeyCode and walk throught the list: {"t1", "t1a" , "t1b",  "t1c"}.
        //if the value of "index" is be negative or over range we will rearrange it.
        
        if (e.KeyCode.ToString()=="Up")   index--;  if (index < 0)  index=mylist.Count-1;
        if (e.KeyCode.ToString()=="Down") index++;  if (index >= mylist.Count) index=0;
        
        //Set the desired textbox to be focused.
        Controls[mylist[index]].Focus(); 

    }
```

Comment: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error

Comment: @Aiman, Can you tell me please in which line you get this error?

Comment: in this line `Controls[mylist[index]].Focus(); `

Comment: @Aiman, **try** to use `this.Controls[mylist[index]].Focus();`